# I cannot find AudioKitUI

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, audiokit

I used the SPM to download AudioKit but whenever I try to import AudioKitUI into a file, I'm told its not found. I've tried using cocoapods and directly loading the pods 'AudioKit/UI' to fix it but to no success. I am a first time user of AudioKit and it seems every time I run into a problem and fix it, Ill find a couple more.

Answer (score 1):

In the [migration guide](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v5-main/docs/MigrationGuide.md#lesser-differences) to AudioKit v5, you will find the following paragraph in the lesser differences section:

> AudioKitUI is no longer a separate framework. You can delete any imports of this. Some of the widgets that were inside of this framework have been removed entirely, but the important stuff, like waveform display, are now included in AudioKit.

So just use `import AudioKit` and delete `import AudioKitUI`.

Comment: Of course it was that simple, thank you!! Now I just need to figure out why my AKKeyboardView isn't in scope.

Comment: import UIKit
import AudioKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadKeyboard()
    }

    func loadKeyboard() {
        //set new variable that is piano kayboard
        
        let keyboardView = AKKeyboardView(frame: ScreenControl.manageSize(rect: CGRect(x:0,y:200,width:800,height:250)))
        self .view.addSubview(keyboardView)
        
    }

}

Comment: I have never used AudioKit, so I don't know what's going wrong. This is also out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 1):

kn-ada97, you should accept Palle's answer it is correct.

For the answer to your second question, AKKeyboardView has been renamed KeyboardView. In version 5 the "AK" has been dropped.

I have found the best way to learn the audiokit 5 stuff is the Cookbooks project. I found the answer to your keyboard question by searching it for "keyboardview". Most older examples or questions here on stack over flow are for 4.

https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook

I just got into Audiokit myself, it's awesome.